# Ionic angular autofill taking back to previous page

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, angular8, ionic5

Hi I am working on ionic application where in first page I am requesting for mobile number when user entered number they will receive OTP and go to next page OTP validation during this time if user selects autofill code page is redirecting to previous page . I had used autocomplete to off to not autocomplete input but still its asking for autofill how to solve this issue please help me as soon as possible because app is already in live many customers facing this issue.

Mobile Number requesting page : -

```
  sign_up() {
   navigator['app'].clearHistory(); 
   if (this.mob_number.toString().length == 10) {
   let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      phone: this.mob_number,
    },
  };
   this.route.navigate(["./verification"], navigationExtras);
   } else {
   alert("Enter Valid 10 digit Mobile Number");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Needs more clarity about what u need to achieve

Comment: HI @MostafaHarb the thing is when we close app while we are in OTP page and come back to app its going to sign in page again

Comment: so u get the code and minimize app to background then get the code and want to enter the app so it redirects u to the sign in page? or I misunderstood?